# In Java, there is a collection which I can take an element only after a time?

Tags: java, collections, thread-safety, web-crawler, timedelay

I'm doing an webcrawler, and I want to not overload the servers with requests, so I will limit the access to the servers by time.

I will have an object/collection that is an list of links that I will visit.

I get the first link and it's from Google(example), visit and do all the work. I only can take another link that is from Google after 20 seconds(example) and while I waiting, I get links from other domains.

Summarizing, I need a collection that allow me to classify the objects inside it and get the objects from it in determined intervals.

There is some similar to this? If not, what collections are recommend to use in the implementation? This collection will be access by various threads.

Comment: Thats a perfect example for smart map/reduce jobs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [DelayQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html) for this. It's a concurrent collection that only allows items to be taken from it once they have "expired". The items you add must implement [Delayed](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Delayed.html).

You might also just want to use a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). For example, for each domain you were crawling, you could schedule a task that grabs the next link, then re-schedules another task with the next link.

Comment: Neat! I wasn't aware of those classes. I was about to suggest an approach where the links were in a simple queue and when one was visited, that domain's entry was updated with a new timestamp in a separate hashtable. Same overall effect of the DelayQueue, but far less elegant. +1 sir.

Comment: @jpm I was to try the same solution that you provide, but I will try the DelayQueue. I wasn't aware of it too.

Comment: Worked. I'm using a queue with links divided per domain that implements the Delayed interfaced and in another class, an DelayQueue with all the links queue inside it.